# Receive array of data and access employee info fields

Tags: php, php5

This method receives an array of data and does some stuff in a database.  I need to get some reviews on it if possible.

```
public function doSomeStuff($arr = array())
{
    $id = $arr['Employee']['id'];
    $name = $arr['Employee']['name'];
    $status = $arr['Employee']['status'] == 'Disabled' ? 0 : 1;
    $user_id = $arr['Employee']['user_id'];
    $query = "update `mytable` set `status` = $status, `name`=$name   WHERE `user_id` = ?";
    self::_runthis($query, array($user_id));
}
```

I am looking to see if this is fool-proof for the data it will receive and will process it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Instead of accessing the employee key every time, just pass in the array rooted at the Employee key
- What happens if all of the array indexes are not set?  You should either check for that or use an object on which you know they all exist

  - Important mostly for data integrity (what if you create an Employee array somewhere and forget a status or something?)
  - But also accessing non-set array keys issues a notice
- I suspect there's something wrong with your class design as a whole.  In particular, the same class should probably not have a method to update an employee and a method to run a query (you don't happen to have something extending some vague DB class do you...?)
- Why is `name` not a place holder like the user_id?
- Use real names when posting code here -- doSomeStuff is very vague, and that hampers our ability to review
- A text status should probably not be being passed into this since it seems like you're dealing with a low level record here
- Don't quote entity names unless you need to.  It breaks compatibility across SQL-dialects for no reason
- What if `$name` has spaces?  What if it has a `'` in it?  Look into SQL injection and prepared statements.  (They're not just about security.  There also about correctness.  In it's current form, your code has a very major bug.)
- A default value for the parameter shouldn't be provided.  Would you want someone to call `$obj->doSomeStuff();`